# 301 redirection removes UTM tags from URLs

Tags: google-analytics, htaccess, 301-redirect, url-rewriting

A page redirects to another page using a `301` redirect in a *.htaccess* file.
If I try to access the page from a URL with UTM tagging, after redirection, it removes all UTM tagging.

Is this normal behavior? How can we keep the UTM tagging so that we can see this in our analytics?

Here are some examples:

***Example 1:***

`http://example.com/page.html?utm_source=nosource&utm_medium=nomedium&utm_campaign=nocam`

redirects to:

`http://example.com/another-page.html`

***Example 2:***

`http://example.com/page.html?utm_source=nosource&utm_medium=nomedium&utm_campgn=nocam&page=1` (Just misspelled `utm_camaign` to check if `utm_` is not just a culprit)

redirects to:

`http://example.com/another-page.html?utm_campgn=nocam&page=1`

***Example 3:***

`http://example.com/page.html?utm_source=nosource&utm_medium=nomedium&utm_campaign=nocam&page=1`

redirects to:

`http://example.com/another-page.html?page=1`

***Example 4:***

`http://example.com/page.html?page=1`

redirects to:

`http://example.com/another-page.html?page=1`

---

### Excerpt from `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^home-living/furniture/([^/\.]+)\.html http://www.example.com/home-living/furniture/filter/cat/$1.h‌​tml [R=301,L]
```

Comment: "If I try to access the page from a URL with UTM tagging, after redirection, it removes all UTM tagging." - That reads as if you are clicking a link on a page, and the page the link is on has UTM tagging? But is the link that is being clicked, and ultimately redirected, have the UTM tagging parameters?

Answer (score 1):

If your .htaccess has `RewriteRule`s like these:

```
RewriteRule page.html /another-page.html [NC,R=301,L]
```

It will always remove querystring parameters, that's default behaviour. You'll have to add `QSA` flag to your `RewriteRule`, like this:

```
RewriteRule page.html /another-page.html [NC,QSA,R=301,L]
```

[Apache mod_rewrite doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)
[QSA|qsappend](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

Comment: tried using `QSA` but still same behavior

Comment: @ganesh could you post your htaccess or at least an excerpt?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^home-living/furniture/([^/\.]+)\.html http://www.example.com/home-living/furniture/filter/cat/$1.html [R=301,L]` Query string work fine except `utm_source`, `utm_medium` and `utm_campaign`. Why only these removed from query string?

Comment: "It will always remove querystring parameters, that's default behaviour." - Actually, the _default_ is the opposite. If you aren't including a query string on the _substitution_ (as in the example), then the query string is passed through from the request unaltered. However, if you include a query string on the _substitution_ then this will discard the query string on the request. You only _need_ the `QSA` flag if you explicitly include a query on the _substitution_ and you want to merge this with whatever query string is included on the request.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^home-living/furniture/([^/\.]+)\.html http://www.example.com/home-living/furniture/filter/cat/$1.h‌​tml [R=301,L]
> ```

This directive *preserves* the entire query string from the original request. It does not remove it, or any part of it. The query string is preserved by default with `RewriteRule` (and `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch`) directives. Only when you explicitly define a new query string on the *substition* (URL target) is the query string replaced (in its entirety). Only then would you need the `QSA` (Query String Append) flag in order to append the original query string to the query string stated in the *substitution* string in order to preserve it - if that is required.

What is described here in examples 2, 3 and 4 is selective removal of specific URL parameters. This is certainly not caused by the above directive. If this is caused by directives in `.htaccess` at all then there must be a specific section / group of directives elsewhere in the file (or server config) that does this. And this is likely resulting in at least two redirects (which would seem to be implied by your statement: "after redirection, it removes all UTM tagging").

However, if this is the case then I would also expect these `utm_` parameters to be removed from any requested URL, regardless of whether that URL is redirected or not.

We would need to see the entire `.htaccess` file in order to progress with this further, otherwise, this is quite likely to be triggered elsewhere in the application logic, particularly if it's only occurring "after redirection".

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add this line in you .htaccess files if you want to execute and delete the utm analytics from the URL

```
#REDIRECTION UTM CLEAR
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "utm" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L,QSD]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I edited the code to fix the closing `</IfModule>` directive (although the `<IfModule>` wrapper should arguably be removed altogether). However, The OP is not wanting to _remove_ UTM parameters from the URL - the removal of UTM parameters would seem to be "problem" they are trying to resolve. (_Aside:_ But if you are trying to remove UTM parameters then the regex `utm` is arguably too general and matches too much. Perhaps `(?:^|&)utm_\w+=` would be preferable. But the `RewriteRule` removes _all_ URL parameters, not just the `utm_` parameters, which may or may not be a problem.)